# Printing Special Escape Sequences

Tags: java

I have a string (pulled from the web) which may look like this: \something\to\do. When I print this string via System.out.println \s \t and \d are treated as escape sequences. How can I print the sting in such a way so that escape sequences are ignored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to escape the backslashes:

```
String s = "\something\to\do";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\", "\\\\")); // prints "\something\to\do"
```

Comment: @Boann yep. This was a pretty terrible question _and_ answer. Since this answer is accepted I can't delete it. Feel free to edit it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have the following output:

```
\something\to\do
```

Then you need to double backslash the backslash characters to make them into backslash literals:

```
string myString = "\\something\\to\\do";
```